# Storing dynamic keys of a document in an Array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, message-queue, prisma

I want to create a generic request document that can take different parameters to be consumed by the same endpoint. Example below is in prisma syntax I hope it is self documenting enough.

```
model Request {
    id                     String                @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    params                 String[]
    dynamicValues          JSON
}
```

2 example docs for ref

```
{
  id: "123",
  params: ["dog_name", "cat_name"],
  dynamicValues: {
    "dog_name": "bob",
    "cat_name": "alice",
  }
}
```

---

```
{
  id: "123",
  params: ["restaurant_location", "time"],
  dynamicValues: {
    "restaurant_location": "paris",
    "time": Date("1-1-23"),
  }
}
```

Some context

- I am using prisma, and currently create a new model for each "request type" very annoying and I would like to create even more in the future.
- These requests are sent to a message queue to be consumed by a BE service.

Wanted to know what y'all think about this situation, if this is best practice or not. If there are other suggestions or thoughts on this, Thanks!

Comment: As written, this question looks like it is soliciting opinions.  Have you encountered a problem that needs solving?

Comment: Yes I am soliciting opinions. @Joe, is that an issue and if so do you have a recommendation on where I should put this instead

Comment: Opinion-based questions are discouraged on stackoverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255471/2282634

Comment: Ahh I see, do you have a recommendation on where I should ask these kinds of questions instead